# How to catch raw request/response of web-service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have to make the desktop client which will work with web-service. Client is provided in `.wsdl`(service contracts) and `.xsd`(data contracts). I have generated the client with svcutil.exe. And I have the idea to write to log file all requests/responces in Raw format(like it can be catched in Fiddler2 but though the code) while client is in debug mode. Can you give me any advance on how to do it or just turn me to the right direction.

My generated service is implemention of System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.

Thx a lot.

Comment: You can write a client message inspector: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ought to be able to use SOAPExtensions to capture the message stream, including request headers. You need to configure your extension in your app.config.

See figure 4 in this sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164007.aspx

Here's how to get started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s25h0swd(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

you have three options,

> First: Since you have wsdl you can generate proxy using SoapUI and change the request and run it will show the detailed response.
>
> Second: Since you are using .net client you can attach the process to 3rd party tool. e.g [HttpAnalyser](http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/?gclid=CNqcrLHMzbgCFScF4godZkcA_w)
>
> Third: if you cant buy 3rd party software, use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture any protocol content.